# Can't compile MagickWand using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, imagemagick, magickwand

I couldn't compile my program which uses MagickWand with CMake. I'm getting this error:

```
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable bin/ScreenRecorder
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ScreenRecorder.dir/source/main.cpp.o: in function `std::thread::thread<void (&)(), , void>(void (&)())':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IRFvvEJEvEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IRFvvEJEvEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x20): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ScreenRecorder.dir/source/screenshot.cpp.o: in function `printScrn(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
screenshot.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `MagickWandGenesis'
/usr/bin/ld: screenshot.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `NewMagickWand'
/usr/bin/ld: screenshot.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `MagickReadImage'
/usr/bin/ld: screenshot.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `MagickWriteImage'
/usr/bin/ld: screenshot.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `DestroyMagickWand'
/usr/bin/ld: screenshot.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `MagickWandTerminus'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ScreenRecorder.dir/build.make:99: bin/ScreenRecorder] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/ScreenRecorder.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(ScreenRecorder)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall")
set(source_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/")

find_package(ImageMagick REQUIRED)

include_directories(
  "/usr/include/ImageMagick-6/"
)

link_libraries(
  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"
)

file (GLOB src_files "${source_dir}*.cpp")

add_executable(ScreenRecorder ${src_files})
```

I tried using variables such as **${ImageMagick_MagickWand_INCLUDE_DIR}** and **${ImageMagick_MagickWand_LIBS_DIR}** but it says that *"wand/MagickWand.h" not found*.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Command `link_libraries` expect **library files** as arguments. But you pass a *directory* to it. BTW, CMake should emit a warning at configuration stage about such misuse.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Okey so, I'll pass every library on there to it ? Because I don't know which one(s) to use.

Comment: After `find_package(ImageMagick)` you have a variable named `ImageMagick_LIBRARIES` which contains a list of libraries you need to link. Use this list for link with these libraries. More information about variables set by `find_package(ImageMagick)` call see there: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/module/FindImageMagick.html.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Still same problem, I used `link_libraires(${ImageMagick_LIBRAIRIES} ${ImageMagick_MagickWand_LIBRARIES} ${ImageMagick_MagickCore_LIBRARIES})` but it shows the same error.

Comment: As undefined functions are from `MagickWand`, you probably need to specify it in the COMPONENTS list for `find_package`: `find_package(ImageMagick REQUIRED COMPONENTS MagickWand)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev
`CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find ImageMagick (missing: ImageMagick_MagicWand_EXECUTABLE)
  (found version "6.9.10-23")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindImageMagick.cmake:277 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/code/screen_recorder/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve a similar issue by enclosing the auto-generated variables in quotes:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  "${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProject
  "${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES}"
)
```

The reason that this resolved the issue is that the variables are CMake lists.
Without quotes, they are concatenated to a long string:

```
MESSAGE(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
MESSAGE(${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})

->

1> [CMake] /usr/include/ImageMagick-6/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6
1> [CMake] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so
```

However, with quotes, the different elements of the list are separated using a semicolon:

```
MESSAGE("${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
MESSAGE("${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES}")

->

1> [CMake] /usr/include/ImageMagick-6;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6
1> [CMake] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so
```